# css information box with button

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get this working right, and I am not sure if this solution is correct..

I know I could put multiple divs in my solution but I wanted the code as short as possible..

It is basically a box with a button and some information.. is this the simplest way of doing it?

```
.actionbox {
    width:90%;
padding-top:20px;
padding:20px; 
    background-color: #999999;
    border-left:10px solid #2ecc71;
    display:inline-block;   

    }

.ashbox{background-color:#34495e;color:white;}


.button{
display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
    font-family:'PT Sans',helvetica;

}
h1 { margin:0}
.button,.button.green{background:#69c773;color:#FFF;-webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 0 0 #51a65f;-moz-box-shadow:0 4px 0 0 #51a65f;box-shadow:0 4px 0 0 #51a65f;}

.floatright {float:right;}
.floatleft {float:left;}
```

HTML

```
<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
<div class="actionbox ashbox">

<h1 class="floatleft">Open Box</h1>
<a href="test.html" class="button floatright">Learn More Info</a>

</div>
</div>
```

[Working Demo JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6LHrD/)

Comment: the issue for me, is when i try to add a picture it screws things up..

like this http://jsfiddle.net/6LHrD/1/

I am trying to get the button under the header but it adds to much space

Comment: do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/rahulsharma2r/6LHrD/2/

Comment: I am assuming I would have to add the div around the h1 and button to make it work properly .

Comment: yep this way you can achieve your goal

Answer (score 2):

Your demo you have Given two `div`

You can omit one `div` and achieve the same... Enjoy The Demo :)

http://jsfiddle.net/6LHrD/3/

i added this css

```
margin:0 auto;
display:table;
```

to `.actionbox` class

**After adding Image**
http://jsfiddle.net/6LHrD/7/

Comment: If i am trying to add a picture, without adding extra div's (not that it should matter ) I get something like this..

http://jsfiddle.net/6LHrD/1/

would clearing the floats work?

Comment: what I was trying to do is have the picture on the right... 

header and button on the left ( If i am using a picture that is )